# How to increment a char int array inside a 'for-loop'

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, increment

I have been killing my brain over the last 2 hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. It is supposed to be a brute force algorithm for a small private key for an encryption system;

```
public static char[] Increment(char[] a, int b, char c) {
    if (a[b] < c)
        a[b] += 1;
    else if ((b) > 0) {
        a[b] = '0';
        Increment(a, b-1, c);
    }
    return a;
} 

public static BigInteger StringLayer(char[] str, char[] a) {

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '-') {
            str[i] = a[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
    return new BigInteger(new String(str));
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] Store = {'0', '0', '0', '0'};

    char[] ab1 = {'4', '-', '-', '7', '8', '-', '3', '0', '-'};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        Store = Increment(Store, Store.length - 1, '9');
        System.out.println(Store);
        System.out.println(StringLayer(ab1, Store));
    }
```

An excerpt of the output is as follows;

0001

400780301

0002

400780301

0003

400780301

etc.

I have no idea why the increasing Store variable (which on the output does seem to be increasing) somehow does not increase when it is passed into the StringLayer method. I am convinced that the answer is extremely simple and I am missing something that I should 100% know, but I am honestly stumped and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple but tricky. When you pass `ab1` to your `StringLayer` method you are passing the **reference** therefore by replacing all `-` you modify the **original** array. So after the first call there are no more `-` in the `ab1` array. To prevent this you should create a copy of the array before processing it:

```
  public static BigInteger StringLayer( char[] str, char[] a )
  {

    char[] target = Arrays.copyOf( str, str.length );

    int index = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < target.length; i++ )
    {
      if ( str[ i ] == '-' )
      {
        target[ i ] = a[ index ];
        index++;
      }
    }
    return new BigInteger( new String( target ) );
  }
```